# Minimal set of edges.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There is given complete graph $K_{n}$.

Let $A(n,k)=$minimal (in respect of its size) subset of edges of $K_{n}$ such every $k$-clique has at least one edge in common with this set.

> Find formula for $|A(n,k)|$

I wrote down some examples such $|A(4,3)|=2$ But afterall i can not see the pattern.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Great question. Was this independent study? a homework assignment?

Comment: Nice puzzle!  It took me 10 minutes to convince myself $|A(5,3)| = 4$.  I think we can clearly see the pattern here: $|A(N,3)| = 2^{N-3}$ (just kidding!)

Comment: Oh as it turns out this is a known problem.  If this is homework I can give you some hints, whereas if this is a research problem I can give you the answer.

Comment: @antkam why did you delete your answer>

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo - because it reveals the whole answer and I'm not sure that's appropriate if this is a homework question.  Was my deletion the right thing to do?  Actually, is it still visible?  (If so, I've just caused more confusion, not less...)  Even after months here I'm still not sure what's the "consensus" for situations like this.

Comment: I think it is only visible for people with a lot of reputation

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo - good!  but back to my question: what do you (someone with a lot of reputation) think re: homework vs hints vs complete answer?  i never quite know what's the right level of help...

Comment: I think you should do whatever you feel like doing

Answer (score 1):

Oh, actually this is directly answered by [Turán's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem).

The theorem gives a construction for the $n$-node graph, called the Turán graph $T(n,k-1)$, which has the max number of edges $B(n,k)$ under the constraint that it is free of $k$-cliques.  This is equivalent to saying that starting with $K_n$ you have to delete (color) as many edges as necessary to bring it down to $T(n,k-1)$.  The construction is easy enough that you should be able to figure out $B(n,k)$ and therefore $A(n,k) = {n \choose 2} - B(n,k)$.